# Seemingly simple UINavigationController issue, navigationItem not displaying correctly

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

I have a base `UINavigationController`, and 3 `UIViewController`.

Let's call them `Home, VC2, and VC3`.

I have a storyboard segue from `Home` to `VC2`, and from `VC2` to `VC3`.

Now...  if I call `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]` from within VC3, I get taken back to 'Home' with the top `navigationItem` bar of VC2! What!?

If I simply use the "back" button, the `navigationItem` top bar displays as expected for each of the views...

Can anyone suggest an alternative to `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)`, or `popToViewController:(UIViewController*)`?  Both cause the issue to occur..

EDIT: Also, just to illustrate further what happens:  Once I pop back to Home, the VC2's navigationItem is sitting there and it contains its own title and back button - if I hit the back button, the top bar slides off the right and now the top bar is empty. Again, this doesn't happen when using VC3:back -> VC2:back buttons to get back to Home. Seems like a rather bad thing for UIKit to be doing, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Can you add your code--not necessarily complete but sufficient enough--here for us to better understand the problem?

Comment: This usually happens when you are popping during a push / pop animation. Are there any log messages to this effect? You need to show your code for the push that is causing the problems

Comment: I'm popping just while sitting idly on VC3, nothing else is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figured out what the problem was.

There was actually a different view at the bottom of the stack. I'm fixing bugs in someone else's project, so I was a little hazy on the structure.

So it was more like this:

`Splash > Home > VC2 > VC3`

Somehow, popToRoot from VC3 was going to `Home`, rather than `Splash`. And somehow, the nav bar of `VC2` was appearing after that.  So, inside of `Home`'s `viewDidAppear`, I added `self.navigationController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self];` and the nav bar issue sorted itself out.